# Android - Take a photo and crop

Tags: android, sdk, camera, photo, image

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera/

But, after taking the photo, when the picture is going to be cropped, appears, "loading image..." forever.

I've tried to Toast the "picUri = data.getData();" and it returned null. I've read that in some devices we need to specify filename for picture to be taken, so I tried, but no good results.

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, "file:///tmp/android.jpg");
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
```

I'm testing it in a Galaxy Nexus and a Galaxy 5.

Someone have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @AaronRussell I really don't remember what I've done and if it worked. And I have no longer the application files, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think the file path you are providing to the EXTRA_OUTPUT is wrong. Instead try using something like this:

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tmp/android.jpg";
captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, storagePath);
startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Thank You, but this is still not working .-. I have no idea why this is not working, I just read about. Anyway, I'm continuing trying!